# Clojure - Side Effects Happening Out Of Order

Tags: clojure

While dabbling in Clojure I've written a very basic program to echo whatever the user types into it. However, it doesn't run in a way that I'm perceiving to be natural. Here's the code:

```
(defn goo []
  (print "echo> ")
  (def resp (read-line))
  (print resp)
)
```

I would expect the code to run like this (for me typing in `foo` as the input to `read-line`):

```
user=> (goo)
echo> foo
foonil
```

But instead, the echo and read-line is switched:

```
user=> (goo)
foo
echo> foonil
```

Why does this happen? Is there a subtlety I'm missing?

EDIT: From Joe's answer, the updated correct solution is:

```
(defn goo []
  (print "echo> ")
  (flush)
  (def resp (read-line))
  (print resp)
  (flush)
)
```

Also, the flushes aren't necessary if you use `println` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know nothing of clojure but this sounds like a case of buffers not getting flushed. Figure out how to flush standard out after the print. The println function probably flushes at the end of each line. Try:

```
(defn goo []
  (print "echo> ")
  (flush )
  (def resp (read-line))
  (print resp)
)
```

Comment: That did it! Adding (flush) after the prints got it. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Cool. Now I have a checked answer in a language I don't know. :-)  Glad I could help.

Comment: good skills! Out of curiosity from someone who knows Clojure but not the inner workings of the stdout buffers... why does this problem occur at all? Seems strange that ordering can get changed within a buffer.....

Comment: I don't know Closure so I can only guess. The internal buffer is there to keep the amount of direct I/O to the file system low. But this design was chosen for I/O back when I/O was slow and no one used threads. On line oriented terminals, the data is only sent to the hosting system when you hit enter. This allows the typist to edit the line buffer before sending it to the host system. People don't use terminals any more so this knowledge fades. (Met a programmer last week who never saw a 5.25" floppy....)

Answer (score 14):

Also, please don't use "def" unless you really, really want to define a global variable.  Use "let" instead:

```
(defn goo []
  (print "echo> ")
  (flush)
  (let [resp (read-line)]
    (print resp)
    (flush)))
```

or, shorter

```
(defn goo []
  (print "echo> ")
  (flush)
  (print (read-line))
  (flush))
```