# Clojure, lazy evaluation issue

Tags: clojure

Consider the following code in clojure:

(let [a (find-a), b (find-b)]
  (println a)
  (println b)
)

Where b is a sequence. There are also some println statements in function find-a. 
What I would expect to see in standard outputs is:
a,
results from println statements in find-a,
b.
However, what I do get is :
a,
part of b,
results from println statements in find-a,
rest of b.

Is this due to lazy evaluation of sequences?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing in this code is inherently lazy - it should all get executed in the correct sequence.

However, depending on what `a` and `b` are there could be something lazy embedded inside them, which only gets executed when `(println a)` and `(println b)` are executed. In particular, if `a` and `b` are lazy sequences created with [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map) or something similar then the later parts of the sequences will only get evaluated when execution is forced within the [println](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/println) statement. To be more specific than that, you'd need to describe the internal structure of `a` and `b`.

I actually suspect however that the problem could be due to buffers not getting flushed - see [Clojure - Side Effects Happening Out Of Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388057/clojure-side-effects-happening-out-of-order)

Comment: println should flush automagically. you generally only have to worry about manually flushing if you are using print.